# How to use Time Machine to backup system from ssd

Tags: macos, time-machine, ssd

I added an SSD to my Mac mini and installed macOS Mojave on it. (it is already installed on the HDD) I notice that Time Machine is still backing up from the HDD. How can I change the source drive for Time Machine to the SSD?

Comment: it is going to back up your startup disk, I think. Are you booting from the SSD?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. As  you can see from other comments I am booting from the SSD but it continues to backup from the HDD.